# How do you validate numbers with Ruby On Rails using % operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make sure that numbers coming into this object are divisible by 3.  How do I use the validate on the model to prevent invalid input?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
# your_model.rb
validate :only_valid_numbers

private

    def only_valid_numbers
        if (self.number % 3) != 0
            self.errors[:base] << "Number must be divisible by 3!"
        end
    end
```

Remember that `0 % 3` will be 0, so if you don't want to allow that, change the if statement to:

```
if self.number != 0 and ...etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own simple validation method for this like so:

```
validate :divisible_by_three

def divisible_by_three
  unless attribute%3 == 0
    self.errors.add(:attribute, "is not divisible by 3")
  end
end
```

I don't think any of the built in rails methods so this is probably the best solution.

Tom